# Etiquette for math subscripts and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

It is my first question here, I hope it is not too stupid...

I am writing my thesis in math and I need a lot of subscripts and superscripts. My problem arises since in subscripts and superscripts numbers and capital letters are too big to appear with a small letter.

For instance, I have to write things like `$c_{1}$ or $q_{A*}$` (I know it is not that nice having both `A` and `\*`, but the function is called `$q_{A}$` and the operation `_{*}` has a precise meaning). And it is not that nice.

Then I started using `\scriptscriptstyle` when I have capital letters or numbers (for instance `c_{{\scriptscriptstyle 1}}`. And finally I noticed that several times I have to subscribe things like `_{2g}` or `_{k+1}` and there numbers come back to their original size.

Hence I was wondering whether there is a standard way or etiquette to deal with this issue (since now I feel either I go back to standard style or I start writing things like `u_{{\scriptscriptstyle 2}g}`...)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openright]{book} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}
$Hom_{0}(X)$ or $Hom_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}(X)$?
But then I have also $Hom_{2g-1}(X)$...
Then also $c_{1}$ or $c_{\scriptscriptstyle 1}$ 
Mixed things like $k^{2g-2p+s}$ or $(u_{{\scriptscriptstyle 1}},\ldots,u_{g}, \tilde{u}_{{\scriptscriptstyle 1}}=u_{g+1}, \ldots , \tilde{u}_{g}=u_{2g})$
Also $\omega_{E}$ is quite annoying.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks! I had seen it in other posts but I didn't know how to do...

Comment: You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a small, minimally working example with a screen shot such that users can make advises about the 'correct' style. However, your question possibly 'provokes' rather opinion-based answers/comments, as most times with style-issue questions.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166010/why-is-my-prime-symbol-too-low-and-why-are-my-subscripts-not-scaled-accordingl; see also the [`subdepth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subdepth) package.

Comment: You don't want `$\operatorname{Hom}_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}(X)$`, really; I'm referring to the subscript (`Hom` should be upright). There's no reason for reducing the size. I use `$\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$` all the time, it's just right as it is.

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the standard. The size changes were chosen by Knuth and later people to conform to printing standards, and look nice in general.

When I give advice to the PhD students here, I generally tell them to avoid indexes as far as possible. We generally point to Nicolas Higham's "Mathematical writing" for advice.