# subscripts with capital Letter adjusting [or etiquette]

Tags: typography, subscripts

Sometimes some .tex features or standards seem strange at first glance. One actual case for me are subscripts with capital letters (obligatory because the letters on subscripts came from acknowledged scientist names) that seem too big to me. I want to reduce them. Their height should not be beyond 30% of the mother's. 
See the example bellow:

```
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{C} = \sigma_P + \frac{\sigma_H^2}{\sigma_P}.
\label{Cowling}
\end{equation}
```

[image: condutivities]

Related posts: 
[etiquette-for-math-subscripts-and-superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173570/etiquette-for-math-subscripts-and-superscripts)

[subscripts-not-scaled-accordingl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166010/why-is-my-prime-symbol-too-low-and-why-are-my-subscripts-not-scaled-accordingl)

Ps. I am showing a relation for ionospheric condutivities. Hall, Pedersen, Cowling, paralel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could drop the size by one "style", from `\scriptstyle` down to `\scriptscriptstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Cowling}{{\mathchoice{}{}{\scriptscriptstyle}{}C}}
\newcommand{\Hall}{{\mathchoice{}{}{\scriptscriptstyle}{} H}}
\newcommand{\Pedersen}{{\mathchoice{}{}{\scriptscriptstyle}{} P}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \sigma_{C}   &= \sigma_P + \frac{\sigma_H^2}{\sigma_P} \\
  \sigma_{\Cowling} &= \sigma_{\Pedersen}+ \frac{\sigma_{\Hall}^2}{\sigma_{\Pedersen}} \\
  \Cowling_{\Pedersen} &\neq \Hall
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The above defines `\Cowling`, `\Hall` and `\Pedersen` as the "symbols" `C`, `H` and `P`, respectively. Each symbol is scaled down to `\scriptscriptstyle` - using [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/5764) - when used in a super-/subscript, otherwise they're kept the same.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Using `\sigma^{}_{P}` will move the subscript a bit down, which is all is needed. Using `\scriptscriptstyle` unbalances everything.

Comment: A combination of the solution by @Werner and @egreg solution gives me a nice output. For example `\Cowling^{}_{\Pedersen} &\neq \Hall`

Answer (score 3):

I'd simply add an empty superscript in order to move the subscript down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\add@empty@sup}{\@ifnextchar^{}{^{}}}

\newcommand{\sC}{\sigma_{\!C}\add@empty@sup}
\newcommand{\sP}{\sigma_{\!P}\add@empty@sup}
\newcommand{\sH}{\sigma_{\!H}\add@empty@sup}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sC = \sP + \frac{\sH^{2}}{\sP}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sigma_{C} = \sigma_P + \frac{\sigma_H^2}{\sigma_P}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I reported also the original input for comparison. Note that I refined a bit the macros in order to add a small negative space to push the subscript nearer to the sigma.

[image]